# How to turn a large CSV file into an API?

Tags: api, csv

The CSV file is 11 GB. I want to be able to call it like an API. Are there any services that make this possible? My programming skills are pretty limited.

Comment: That's quite vague question - do you want the API to be available on the net or locally? Do you want the whole file to be downloadable through an API or do you want to access it contents in some specific way?

Comment: @matszwecja Sorry for the vagueness. Available on the net. Accessible in a specific way (it's a business database, so I'd like to be able to call all companies of a certain size).